# Creating a matrix of vectors with apply (or other iterative function) in R

Tags: r, matrix, encoding, lapply, orthogonal

I need to run a orthogonal encoding function over a set of octamers (sets of 8 letters), and return them as a matrix of nx160 numbers (where n is the number of octamers on the data).

The orthogonal coding functions is:

```
  orthocode <- function(octamer){
        matcode <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
        octamer_char <- as.character(octamer)
        octamer_split <- strsplit(octamer_char,"")[[1]]
        for (letter in octamer_split){
           ifelse (letter == "A", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "R", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "N", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "D", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "C", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "Q", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "E", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "G", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "H", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "I", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "L", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "K", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "M", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "F", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "P", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "S", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "T", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "W", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "Y", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))),
           ifelse (letter == "V", (matcode = rbind(matcode,c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)))
           ))))))))))))))))))))
       }
       matcode <- matcode[-1,]
       matcode <- c(matcode)
       return(matcode)
    }
```

AS some have asked, here is an example, even if this is not the part that isn't working:

```
 orthocode("ARNDCQEG")
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [81] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The function is working on individual octamers, but when I try to use lapply on it, the result is just a 160 numbers vector, this time with the code altered (and meaningless).

```
lapply(data[1], orthocode)
```

The result looks like:

```
$V1
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[81] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The orthocode function is actually working. What I need to know is how do I take the octamers from a dataframe, run the fucntion on them and as a result end up with a matrix that looks like this one:

```
rbind(orthocode("ARNDCQEG"),orthocode("NGJKAEPS"),orthocode("ABGSWKLA"))
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
[3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80]
[1,]     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[3,]     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97] [,98] [,99] [,100] [,101] [,102] [,103] [,104] [,105]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     [,106] [,107] [,108] [,109] [,110] [,111] [,112] [,113] [,114] [,115] [,116] [,117] [,118] [,119] [,120] [,121] [,122] [,123] [,124] [,125] [,126] [,127]
[1,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[3,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
     [,128] [,129] [,130] [,131] [,132] [,133] [,134] [,135] [,136] [,137] [,138] [,139] [,140] [,141] [,142] [,143] [,144] [,145] [,146] [,147] [,148] [,149]
[1,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[3,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     [,150] [,151] [,152] [,153] [,154] [,155] [,156] [,157] [,158] [,159] [,160]
[1,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[3,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

The output hase to be a matrix of n rows, 160 columns. On the data I have to run it, the result matrix should be a 947x160 one.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ifelse` is not design to execute code, but rather choose from items in  vectors based on a logical input vector. In this case a fairly inefficient approach would be to convert the `ifelse`'s to `if(test){code1}else{rest_of_code}`. More efficient methods are undoubtedly possible but you have not offered a full example much less a _minimal_ full example.

Comment: Can you please add desired output for several test strings?

Comment: We don't know what you have in `data[1]` and what should be the result for it. Just showing an example for `orthocode("ARNDCQEG")` isn't helpful. It would be helpful if you could show first 2-3 values in `data[1]` and they should handled

Comment: The desired output would be the one shown above for each row. So if we just do it for two octamers it would look like `rbind(orthocode("ARNDCQEG"),orthocode("NGJKAEPS"))`

Comment: First of all you don't have `J` there. Second of all, wouldn't `cbind` make more sense?

Comment: I had a problem using `matcode <- c(matcode)`so I changed them to `cbind`, since it fits the allocation order for R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify `ifelse` with `match`, and drop the `forloop`:

```
orthocode <- function(octamer){
  matcode <- rep(0, 20)
  octamer_char <- as.character(octamer)
  octamer_split <- strsplit(octamer_char,"")[[1]]

  t(sapply(octamer_split, function(letter){
    res <- matcode
    res[ match(letter, c("A","R","N","D","C","Q","E","G","H","I",
                         "L","K","M","F","P","S","T","W","Y","V"))] <- 1
    res
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`switch` has the semantics of the CASE-construct that exists in other languages. Lightly tested in the absence of a good example, but try this instead :

```
orthocode <- function(octamer){
    matcode <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    octamer_char <- as.character(octamer)
    octamer_split <- strsplit(octamer_char,"")[[1]]
    for (letter in octamer_split){ 
        val <- switch( letter,  
       "A" = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "R" = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "N" = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "D" = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "C" = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "Q" = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "E" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "G" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "H" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "I" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "L" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "K" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "M" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "F" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "P" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
       "S" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
       "T" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
       "W" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
       "Y" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
       "V" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
                 )
      matcode=c(matcode,val)
     }
   matcode 
}
```

<strike>Note that I remove the line with `matcode <- c(matcode)` since that has the side-effect of destroying the matrix structure.</strike> With this:

```
dat <- list("ARNDE", "CQEGD")
```

I get:

```
     t( sapply(dat, orthocode) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32]
[1,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77]
[1,]     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97] [,98] [,99] [,100] [,101] [,102] [,103] [,104] [,105] [,106]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
     [,107] [,108] [,109] [,110] [,111] [,112] [,113] [,114] [,115] [,116] [,117] [,118] [,119]
[1,]      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[2,]      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     [,120]
[1,]      0
[2,]      0
```

I like the result better if I use this at the end (but it's not what you anted):

```
    matcode <- matcode[-1, ,drop=FALSE]
    rownames(matcode) <- octamer_split
    return(matcode)  # here the return call is needed.
```

Comment: I don't think `switch` + growing objects in a loop is a good practice for something that could very easily vectorized

Comment: Thanks for the advice about `switch`, it really looks better now. `matcode <- c(matcode) was there on purpose since it's one of the requisites. The result matrix have to be 160xn, and that 160 is the matrix of each octamer transformed into a vector. The problem is not with the function, but that I don't know how to create the matrix with the individual results.

Comment: If you want a matrix (with values in columns) then just use `sapply` and transpose if you need in rows. It's considered good manners to upvote useful responses.

Comment: I'll modify my code to jsut retrun a 160 length vector and demonstrate my suggestion on some pentamers.

Comment: The combination of `t()`and `sapply()`made it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

R is vectorized. Forget about running a separate code chunk for each case. Don't grow objects in loops. I would simply go with

```
orthocode <- function(octamer) {

  # Predifine identity matrix
  m <- diag(20) 

  # Predefine values vector (no "J" or "B" here btw)
  rownames(m) <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "Q", "E", "G", "H", "I", "L",
                   "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V") 

  # Create a character vector for each input
  octamer_split <- strsplit(as.character(octamer), "", fixed = TRUE)

  # match values for each value
  t(sapply(octamer_split, function(x) m[match(x, rownames(m)),])) 

}
```

This function will work for both a single input or a vector. You could test it using

```
orthocode(c("ARNDCQEG", "NGJKAEPS", "ABGSWKLA"))
```

Or in your case using just

```
orthocode(data[, 1])
```

---

P.S.

You don't have `J` or `B` in your vector so not sure how it should be dealt for your example. In this case it returns `NA`s